# Kibana: Using Terms Query by index in dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently using [Terms Query by index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup-params) to filter a query:

```
{
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "test.type.name": {
                      "index": "test-type-index",
                      "id": "unit-test",
                      "path": "type.name"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "test.env": {
                      "value": "dev"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
    }
```

Example of `test-type-index`:

```
{
        "_index": "test-type-index",
        "_id": "unit-test",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
            },
            {
              "name": "test2",
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I am trying to create a dashboard based on this query.
How can I create these visualisations?

- Create visualisation based on the above query. I managed to use DSL to filter the results in discover using this query but not the visualisation.
- Create an option list of test-type-index ids then use the type names to filter another visualisation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet possible to create a dashboard control based on the `terms` lookup query, but there's [ongoing work](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/124791) on this and that might be added in the future.

Right now, you can add that query directly into the DSL tab of a new custom filter, but that's pretty much it.